# How do I remove the top of a ceiling light can

Tags: ceiling

I am working on a 21 year old ceiling can light that is 30' in the air. The bulb is burnt out and I have twisted out the electrical bulb socket from the can light housing. I need to open the top of the can light and reinsert the bulb socket. I cannot get the top open in the attic and do not want to damage the ceiling by pulling too hard. Attached is photos of the ceiling can light from the attic and ceiling views. The can light top seems to be secured by only two small indents - 180 degrees from each other. But, I can not remove the can light top no matter how much I pull on it.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Glenn

[image: ceiling can light]

Comment: Can someone tell me the model # of this 21 year old ceiling light can posted above.  Thanks,  Glenn

Comment: The cans are usually spot welded together, way two many brands to guess but there is normally a manufacturers tag on the can. I hope you have a man lift to work on it that would be a pain on a ladder.

Comment: Is replacing the entire canlight unit an option? (It may have to be)

Comment: Not 100% certain I can visualize the problem.  It sounds like you unscrewed the socket from the housing and that there may have been a bolt holding the socket to the inside of the housing, but the bolt was on the outside of the top of the housing.  You might have to get creative, or just do some drywall work to repair the mess after fixing it.

Comment: I can't see what you've done, so I can't guess how to fix that.